# How do I change the display name on google calendar invites?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Currently using Gsuite for the organization, and uses Google Calendar API to send invites to users.
the problem is the Display Name in the Inbox email shows `info` (emails address of info@organization.com)
want to change it as the Organization Name but nowhere I can find where to do that.

below is my code for creating an event

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => $summary,
    'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => $start,
        'timeZone' => 'UTC',
    ),
    'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => $end,
        'timeZone' => 'UTC',
    ),
    'attendees' => array(
        array('email' => $email, 'organizer' => true, 'responseStatus' => 'accepted'),
    )
));
$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event, ['sendNotifications' => $notify, 'sendUpdates' => 'all']);
```

please see image attached.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you're not creating the event via UI, you could use Gmail API in your application so that  you can send a customized invitation email, setting your desired the display name. How are you creating the event?

Comment: @Iamblichus in creating the event using Google Calendar API.
tested both via API and sending invite thru Calendar API

Comment: @DaImTo updated my post with code.

Comment: Let me clarify this before posting an answer, you basically want to change the subject of the email invites from ```info``` to ```organization_name```, am I right?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf want to change the From name (info) to my organization name

Comment: I believe the ```from``` you are getting is basically the organiser name. According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) you can access this property in ```organizer.displayName```. Let's first make sure this is the case. Could you please log the ```organizer.displayName``` of the event you are creating to see if it is **info**?

Answer (score 0):

the answer lies within "Google Currents". Make sure "Currents" is enabled as an app for your organization, then click it to go into the settings. Make sure "Profile Creation" is automatically turned on in Advance Settings. After, go the Profiles section ( https://admin.google.com/u/0/ac/gplus/users ), and then activate the profile for the user/account you want. Once their profile is activated, the displayName property will be filled when retrieving Calendar Event info!!!